# Do I need the definite article before a noun followed by No. ...?

Tags: definite-article

Do I need the definite article before "purchase order". What is the rule?

> I`ve got some questions about purchase order No. 1234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't.

It's correct to omit the definite article when we specify an item or place:

> The car is parked outside Apartment 6
>   Please check the contents of package number 10
>   You are seated in row 5

The guideline is:

Use the indefinite article before the first mention:

> I saw A dog outside A house in THE town

Both the dog and the house are unspecified. The town is understood.

> I think I saw THE dog outside THE same house.

The speaker now refers back to the dog and the house already mentioned.

In your example:

> There is A purchase order on the desk
>   Is it THE purchase order from the plumber, No 1357
>   No, it's purchase order No 1234 from the electrician.

Note, however, that these are merely guide examples and that the use of articles is full of traps for the unwary.

http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html
https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/articles.aspx